# How to use MVC route in ASP.NET WebAPI project

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, asp.net-web-api

I have a web API and i want to add a few asp.net pages to manage aspects of the API.

In the WebApiConfig.cs file i have a couple of routes, with the following being used as my catch all route for the API.

```
config.Routes.MapHttpRoute(name: "CatchAll",routeTemplate: "{controller}/{action}/{id}",defaults: new { id = RouteParameter.Optional });
```

I want to add a new section that is prefixed by /control to push to the asp.net side of things. To do this i have added the following to RouteConfig.cs

```
    routes.MapRoute(
        name: "Default",
        url: "control/{controller}/{action}/{id}",
        defaults: new { controller = "Home", action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional }
    );
```

I have then added a standard controller that i will use to manage things.

```
public class ManageController : Controller
{
    public ActionResult Index()
    {

        return Content("Works");
    }
}
```

When i visit /control/manage in the browser i get the following error.

> No type was found that matches the controller named 'control'

It looks like the route is being completely bypassed or at best, the catch all from the api route is catching it and giving it priority. IS there a way i can make the request catch this route without having to create a separate project?

Comment: If you use the `[RoutePrefix]` attribute on the individual controllers that would work. It won't be a one-size-fits-all solution but it will make more sense IMO if you only have certain routes nested under control. FYI the attribute may be `[Route]` depending on the version of ASP.NET you use.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The order of registration is matter 
You need to register

```
public class RouteConfig {

    public static void RegisterRoutes(RouteCollection routes) {

        routes.IgnoreRoute("{resource}.axd/{*pathInfo}");

        routes.MapRoute(
                name: "DefaultMVC",
                url: "control/{controller}/{action}/{id}",
                defaults: new { controller = "Home", action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional }
            );
        //..other routes.
    }
}
```

in the `RouteConfig.cs` before

```
config.Routes.MapHttpRoute(name: "CatchAll",routeTemplate: "{controller}/{action}/{id}",defaults: new { id = RouteParameter.Optional });
```

in the `WebApiConfig.cs` file.

What happens in your case is that the `/control/manage` url is handled by `CatchAll` route thus mapping control to a controller and manage to an action

In  order to do that  register them in Global.asax in the following order:

```
RouteConfig.RegisterRoutes(RouteTable.Routes);
GlobalConfiguration.Configure(WebApiConfig.Register);
```

Comment: How do i do this? The webapi route file doesnt support the asp mvc route. The routes registered in the webapi method only work with controllers that inherit ApiController

Comment: change order of registration in Global.asax (see in the answer)

Comment: @DanHastings that is why, as shown in the above answer you manage the MVC routes in the `RouteConfig.cs` file, and make sure that it is registered before the Web API routes. the MVC controllers will inherit from `Controller`